# Populate a gridview with user-input data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating a WebForms page which will be use to insert questions into a database. I want the user to input the question and then it's alternatives (options). For example:

> What does "Soviet" mean?
>
> - German
> - Council
> - None of the above

As I can't foresee how many alternatives each question's going to have, I'd like to present the user with an input field for him to type in an alternative, and a button which will display it in a gridview (which is initially not visible), and then clear the input field for a new alternative to be typed in. Finally, at the end of the page, there's a button which will save everything to the database.

The question is saved in a database called Tests, and the alternatives are saved to another db (named Options). I only want the alternatives to be insert together with the question itself.

How can I dinamically populate the 'Alternatives' gridview like that? Where can I keep the information entered by the user while he fills the form, before submitting them for insertion?
A friend of mine told me to have a look at datatables, but I'm fairly newbie to asp.net and would appreciate an elaborate answer.
Also, is it possible to save the contents of the gridview to the database later on?

Thanks

Comment: So where is your effort? SO is not a "I want software, you make it for me?"- kind of site.

Comment: Yes you can save your gridview values as you want at the end. But we need, what you tried till now ?. SO that we can continue from where you struggling.

Comment: @matthijs: It is a question and answers website. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, but rather for someone to teach me or point me the way.

Comment: @gkrishy: The last paragraph of my question is exactly what I need help with. I have no problem saving the question itself to the database, or even a single alternative. I simply do not know how to fill in the gridview dinamically.

Comment: @Marc.2377 Have you tried with my answer ?. What's the result ?

Comment: @gkrishy Not yet, I'm working with something else right now. But your answer looks good and understandable, I'll probably have no problem following on it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Fine. If you think the answer is okay or the answer is helpful to others, then please mark my answer as correct. So that others may find the things easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here am giving you a layout for your question, please let me know if you face any confuse with this,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack == false)
  {
    DataTable date = new DataTable();
    date.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(string));
    date.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(string));
    Session["dte"] = date;
  }
}

protected void addbutton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  DataTable date = (DataTable)Session["dte"];
  DataRow dr = date.NewRow();
  dr["Column 1"] = TextBox1.Text.Trim();// Your Values
  dr["Column 2"] = TextBox2.Text.Trim();// Your Values
  date.Rows.Add(dr);
  GridView1.DataSource = date;
  GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

You must store your values into datatable using session, then finally you need to add your datatable values into grid view on button click.

Comment: There's an spelling error at line 6, but besides that, your answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry and thanks. I have changed the error which you mentioned at line 6.

Comment: Can you explain what does the lines of code in page load does? When wrote only the click event code, I got a null reference exception. Does this initialize the grid(I don't know why :( ). Please attach any reference to read the details from.

Comment: In page load, I have created a datatable with columns. Hence without creating columns, if you pass values, then definitely you will get null reference exception. Instead, you can directly create columns in click event itself.